# Можно ли вызвать метод класса-родителя после его переопределения (Java)?

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

И снова наступаю на грабли, переходя от теории к практике.

Есть абстрактный класс `Animal`. У этого класса есть метод `makeNoise(),` который выводит на экран сообщение "Я животное!". Также есть классы `Cat` и `Dog`, которые унаследованы от супер-класса `Animal`. В каждом из них я переопределил метод `makeNoise()`. Теперь в зависимости от того, кошка была создана, или собака, метод выводит на экран "Мяу" или "Гав".

Но! Допустим, появилась необходимость у объекта типа `Cat` вызвать метод `makeNoise()`, но не свой метод, который выдаст нам "Мяу", а метод супер-класса, который скажет нам "Я животное". Как это реализовать? Мои попытки ниже, результата 0, вызывается переопределенный метод :(

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /*Объекты типа animal*/
        Animal cat = new Cat("Маруся");
        Animal dog = new Dog("Шарик");

        /*Объекты своих собственных типов*/
        Cat cat2 = new Cat("Маруся 2");
        Dog dog2 = new Dog("Шарик 2");

        System.out.println("-------------------");

        cat.makeNoise();
        cat2.makeNoise();
    }
}

public abstract class Animal {
    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        name = this.name;
        return name;
    }

    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println("Я животное!!11!!");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal {

    public Cat(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
        System.out.println("Новая кошка создана. Ее имя: " + getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " Сказала: " + "Мяу мяу");
    }
}

public class Dog extends Animal {
    public Dog(String name) {
        this.setName(name);
        System.out.println("Новая собака создана. Ее имя: " + getName());
    }

    @Override
    public void makeNoise() {
        System.out.println(getName() + " Сказала: " + "Гав гав");
    }
}
```

*P.S.* Скажите, пожалуйста, присутствует ли в описанном мною примере полиморфизмом?

Answer (score 8):

Это делается так:

```
super.makeNoise();
```

Comment: Ниже объяснили, что я кое-что не так понял, но все же хочется применить ваш метод, посмотреть, что будет.. Как мне применить это в main? Пробовал super.cat.makeNoise(); и по другому.. никак.. Или это нужно в классах животных описать? Но если это так, то получается, что из main я не могу у cat вызвать метод его родителя (Animal)? Голова кругом от ООП :D

Comment: `super` можно использовать, только чтобы обратиться к своему классу-родителю, к чужому нельзя. Так что надо это в классе соответствующего животного писать. А "снаружи" можно вызвать только одну версию метода - самую последнюю в смысле переопределения, это называется виртуальные методы (см. c++).

Answer (score 2):

Видно, что ваш вопрос появился после [вашего предыдущего вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557219/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-java/557406#557406).

Видимо, вы не совсем понимаете на данный момент для чего полиморфизм нужен. 
Суть как раз-таки в том, что вы имеете у разных типов одну сигнатуру методов (одинаковые названия методов с одним возвращаемым типом и одинаковымыми передаваемыми типами) но код в этих методах разный.

Для этого вам и нужно наследование, вы получаете не только доступ к коду родителя и интерфейс доступа(одинаковая сигнатура), хотя при проектировании лучше использовать , если это возможно, интерфейсы.

Напоминаю, что Полиморфизмом назвается возможность работать с несколькими типами так, как будто это один и тот же тип и в то же время поведение каждого типа будет уникальным в зависимости от его реализации.

Вы же делаете наоборот, имеете наследников, но пытаетесь вызывать код родителя.

Comment: Благодарю, а я понял в свое время полиморфизм как возможность вызывать код родительских классов.. Еще раз спасибо :)

Answer (score 1):

```
public void makeNoise() {
   this.super().makeNoise();
}
```

Не помню так ли,  но что-то  с `super` это  точно