# Почему приведение типов к базовому не заставляет выполнять метод базового типа?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование, полиморфизм

Учусь программировать. У меня есть классы (Базовый и производный). Когда в тестере вызываю метод draw(), то почему то отрабатывает как "PensilWithPen DRAW". Хотя я же привел к типу "Pen", и метод должен выполнятся из его тела?

Как мне сделать так, чтобы у объекта value вызвать метод draw() и чтобы он выполнил "PEN DRAW"

```
public class FirstClassTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Box<Pen> box = new Box();

    box.set(new PensilWithPen());

    Pen value = box.get();

    value.draw();

}

}
class Pen{

      public void draw(){
           System.out.println("PEN DRAW");
      }
}
class PensilWithPen extends Pen{

      public void draw(){
           System.out.println("PensilWithPen DRAW");
      } 
}
```

Comment: override?(хз как устроено в яве, но без override тяжко компилятору понять чего вы от него хотите)

Comment: @ВладимирКлыков В яве все методы виртуальные

Comment: @AntonShchyrov я обратного и не утверждал, и так же прямо сказал что не уверен как должна себя вести ява =)

Comment: Override не обязательно писать. Он пишется для удобства программиста.

Answer (score 2):

Это называется [полиморфизм](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_(%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)#%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2).

В Java если метод переопределен, то при вызове выполняется реализация метода, соответствующая реальному (`PensilWithPen`) типу объекта, а не объявленному (`Pen`) типу переменной. Методы с такой механикой вызова называются [виртуальными](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%92%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4). В Java все методы виртуальны.

Виртуальные методы позволяют обращаться к разным реализациям используя метод, определенный в родителе. Например:

```
//получаем pen, сгенерированный в другом классе
Pen pen = (new PenGenerator()).createPen();
//ручка рисует
pen.draw();
```

Так мы можем в любой момент заменить ручку в генераторе ручек (`PenGenerator`). При этом вызывающий код не нужно будет переписывать.

Еще пример:

```
Pen[] pens = new Pen[]{pen, penWithPencil};
for(Pen pen : pens) {
    //каждая ручка рисует по-своему, но метод всегда вызывается одинаково
    pen.draw();
}
```

Та же логика применяется к методам интерфейсов. Поэтому к ним можно обратиться через интерфейс:

```
interface Pen {
    void draw();
}

class PensilWithPen implements Pen{
      public void draw(){
           System.out.println("PensilWithPen DRAW");
      } 
}

...
Pen pen = new PensilWithPen();
//ручка рисует, хотя в самом Pen нет реализации
pen.draw();
```

Почитайте: [Как на практике применяется полиморфизм?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/935362/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC)

### Как вызвать метод родителя?

В том виде, в котором Вы реализовали два класса — никак.

Если нужно вызывать от объекта класса-наследника обе реализации, то потребуется определить два метода.

Либо не переопределять метод вообще, а добавить новый:

```
class PensilWithPen extends Pen{
      public void drawWithPencil(){
           System.out.println("PensilWithPen DRAW");
      } 
}
...
PensilWithPen pensilWithPen = new PensilWithPen();
Pen pen = pensilWithPen;
//рисуем
pen.draw();
//рисуем по-новому
pensilWithPen.drawWithPencil();
```

Либо переопределить метод, но оставить вариант для вызова старого метода:

```
class PensilWithPen extends Pen{
      public void draw(){
           System.out.println("PensilWithPen DRAW");
      } 
      public void drawPen(){
           super.draw();
      } 
}
...
PensilWithPen pensilWithPen = new PensilWithPen();
Pen pen = pensilWithPen;
//рисуем по-новому
pen.draw();
//рисуем по-старому
pensilWithPen.drawPen();
```

Смотрите еще: [Можно ли вызвать метод класса-родителя после его переопределения (Java)?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/557291/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-java)

Answer (score 0):

Потому, что так и задумано.

В абсолютном большинстве случаев программисту нужно именно чтобы вызывался метод производного класса. А приведение типа к базовому - лишь способ поместить объекты разных классов в один контейнер.